# Iterating over arrays Boxes

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Box 1 dimensions
        int x1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int y1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int z1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] box1 = {x1, y1, z1};
        Arrays.sort(box1);
        x1 = box1[0];
        y1 = box1[1];
        z1 = box1[2];
        // Box 2 dimensions
        int x2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int y2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int z2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] box2 = {x2, y2, z2};
        Arrays.sort(box2);
        x2 = box2[0];
        y2 = box2[1];
        z2 = box2[2];
        if (x1 < x2) {
            if (y1 <= y2) {
                if (z1 <= z2) {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incompatible");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incompatible");
            }
        }
        else if (x1 > x2) {
            if (y1 >= y2) {
                if (z1 >= z2) {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incompatible");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incompatible");
            }
        }
        else if (x1 == x2) {
            if (y1 < y2) {
                if (z1 <= z2) {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incompatible");
                }
            }
            else if (y1 > y2) {
                if (z1 >= z2) {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incompatible");
                }
            }
            else {
                if (z1 < z2) {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2");
                }
                else if (z1 > z2) {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Box 1 = Box 2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me to resolve your code?
I think there are a little mistakes because :

> Failed test #3 of 7. Wrong answer

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:

```
1 3 7
2 8 3
```

Correct output:
`Incompatible`

Your code output:
`Box 1 < Box 2`

Comment: "can you help me to resolve your code" - who are you addressing here?

Comment: `Arrays.sort(box2);` I don't think you need to do this. Try removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always good to start off by formulating the requirement you want to solve. So you want to determine for two boxes with dimensions x, y, z which box will fit into the other, if any. I am assuming that boxes with equal dimensions will not fit into each other.

By sorting the dimensions in ascending order you will compare the two smallest dimensions first, then the second smallest and so on.

A box for which all these sorted dimensions are smaller than those of the other, will fit into the other:

```
box A: 1, 4, 8
box B: 2, 5, 9
1<2, 4<5, 8<9 -> A < B
```

If the sorted dimensions have contradictory rankings, the boxes are incompatible:

```
box A: 1, 3, 7
box B: 2, 8, 3
1<2, 3<8, !7<3 -> Incompatible
```

So I think your code could be much simpler:

```
if (x1 < y1 && x2 < y2 && x3 < y3) {
    System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2");
}
else if (x1 > y1 && x2 > y2 && x3 > y3) {
    System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Incompatible");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your logic. But somehow, not able to. Can you assist me in understanding it? 

specifically this part.

box A: 1, 3, 7
box B: 2, 8, 3
1<2, 3<8, !7<9 -> Incompatible

Comment: There was a typo in this answer, which I fixed now.  !7<9 should be !7<3. So in the second example box A does not fit inside box B because there is no ordering of the dimensions (=rotations of the box) that makes each value of A smaller than a matching value of B.